# UIWebView loads payment gateway(paytm) page url in my app, will Apple approve it?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app for PDF and downloading PDF, I am using using `Paytm` - Third party payment gateway for payments on web view. Without using an "In-App purchase", will it affect the Apple review guidelines?

Comment: It does not affect the Review process as many prominent apps use this method for payments (e.g. Uber, Ola cabs)

Answer (score 0):

In-app currency is only used inside of your app.

> **3.1.1 In-App Purchase:** If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.

For third party payment.

> **3.1.5 Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App:** If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than IAP to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions.

Apple has no issue implementing payment process in `UIWebView` but you have to provide very clear explanation of your payment process to get your app approved without any objection.

Comment: In my App pdf purchase and its digital content, in that case Apple will approve it ?

Comment: If that pdf file can be used outside the app. You have to use third party payment like you are doing now. They will reject the In-App purchases in that case.
Your app might get rejected in any case, then you have to file an appeal and tell them what you are doing. You might have long argument with Apple people and then they will allow your app.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply !

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple guide lines given below, If you are purchasing physical goods which can be consumed out side of the App, then you can go for other payment gateway, else your App will be rejected.

`3.1.5` Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than IAP to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions.

Comment: In my App pdf purchase and its digital content, in that case Apple will approve it ?

Comment: No It will not approve, as you can see the guide line they mentioned if the goods "Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App"  then only you can use other payment gateway.